# Run module with argparse with IPython

Tags: python, ipython, argparse

Say I have this file:

```py
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

If I run it with Python, it works fine:

```
% python -m t --foo
Namespace(foo=True)
```

However, running it with IPython, I get an error:

```
% ipython -m t --foo
usage: ipython [-h] [--debug] [--quiet] [--init] [--autoindent] [--no-autoindent] [--automagic] [--no-automagic] [--pdb] [--no-pdb] [--pprint]
               [--no-pprint] [--color-info] [--no-color-info] [--ignore-cwd] [--no-ignore-cwd] [--nosep] [--autoedit-syntax]
               [--no-autoedit-syntax] [--simple-prompt] [--no-simple-prompt] [--banner] [--no-banner] [--confirm-exit] [--no-confirm-exit]
               [--term-title] [--no-term-title] [--classic] [--quick] [-i] [--profile-dir ProfileDir.location]
               [--profile TerminalIPythonApp.profile] [--ipython-dir TerminalIPythonApp.ipython_dir] [--log-level TerminalIPythonApp.log_level]
               [--config TerminalIPythonApp.extra_config_file] [--autocall TerminalInteractiveShell.autocall]
               [--colors TerminalInteractiveShell.colors] [--logfile TerminalInteractiveShell.logfile]
               [--logappend TerminalInteractiveShell.logappend] [-c TerminalIPythonApp.code_to_run] [-m TerminalIPythonApp.module_to_run]
               [--ext TerminalIPythonApp.extra_extensions] [--gui TerminalIPythonApp.gui] [--pylab [TerminalIPythonApp.pylab]]
               [--matplotlib [TerminalIPythonApp.matplotlib]] [--cache-size TerminalInteractiveShell.cache_size]
               [extra_args [extra_args ...]]
ipython: error: argument --foo: expected one argument
```

How can I run it using `IPython`?

(my end-goal is to run be able to access a running IPython kernel from within my script)

Comment: read the `ipython` help.  It has its own `argparse`.  Look for a way specify arguments for your script.

Comment: Try `ipython -m t -- --foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hpaulj said, you can use `--` as a separator to indicate to IPython to stop processing arguments. This is a [commonly used separator in unix commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean).